# How to send Thredded notifications via the Notice Gem instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications

My Ruby on Rails application uses the [Noticed gem](https://github.com/excid3/noticed) to deliver notifications.

I’ve recently added the [Thredded gem](https://github.com/thredded/thredded) to create a forum section and now I have two different notification icons. One on my main navigation and one just on the thredded forum page.

I currently have the initialise file like this

```
Thredded.notifiers = []
```

which hasn’t disabled the notifications so I am not quite sure where I can modify that.

I tried creating a notification (with Noticed) in the thredded initialise file but that just crashed my app.

```
Thredded.notifiers = [Noticed::ThreddedNotification.with(user: user.id).deliver_later(user)]
```

Where can I modify the notifications?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my own question haha! :)

I generated a Noticed notification file and a custom notification controller as Thredded has some specific methods. Then in the initialise file I called a new instance of that controller class.

Thredded initialise file

```
Thredded.notifiers = [CustomThreddedNotiferController.new]
```

Noticed Notification file

```
class ForumNotification < Noticed::Base
  
  deliver_by :database
  
  param :user

  def user
    User.find(params[:user])
  end
  
  def message
    t(".message")
  end

  def url
    root_path
  end
end
```

Custom Controller

```
class CustomThreddedNotiferController < ApplicationController
  def initialize
  end

  def human_name
    'hello'
  end

  def key
    'email'
  end

  def new_post(post, users)
    user = User.find_by(id: users[0])
    ForumNotification.with(user: user.id).deliver_later(user)
  end

  def new_private_post(post, users)
    #
  end
end
```